# PushViewController makes image disappear

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, background-image

I'm using:

```
GroceryDetailViewController *detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"groceryDetail"];     
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

to open a new viewController. When the user finishes work in the detailViewController, this method gets called:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Now, when back to the first view, the navBar background image disappeared. Originally I set it with:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Title-Bar-(Blue).png"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Even when I try to reset the background image inside

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

it stays disappeared. (It gets called, I checked with NSLog.)

What happens here? Thank you!

Update: I noticed that the detailVC in some way extends the firstVC because a custom, programatically created label inside the navBar still is on its place after the push. It doesn't belong to the detailVC at all. Maybe I need a different push method or something that "creates" a "fresh" new vc. Someone got an idea?

Comment: Could someone else be setting the background image in, say, viewWillDisappear of the GroceryDetailViewController?

Comment: No. Until now the GroceryDetailVC doesn't even has a title or own image. It's like the GroceryDetailVC is overwriting its parentVC in some kind...

Comment: What if you set the background image globally with `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage...`?

Comment: Well the problem is that these two VCs are supposed to have two different navBar backgrounds.

Comment: Why don't you try creating a simple project with two view controllers and see if you can create a reproducible test case of the problem?